# SelectField wrapped in component doesn't display initial selects

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have problem with SelectField wrapped in stateless functional component.

```
const Select = (props) => {
  const { options } = props;
  const items = Object.keys(options).map((option, i) =>
    <MenuItem key={i} value={option} primaryText={options[option]} />
  );

  return (
    <SelectField
      style={props.style}
      floatingLabelText={props.label}
      value={props.value}
      onChange={props.onChange.bind(null, props.name)}
    >
      {items}
    </SelectField>
  );
};
```

I'm using it from parent component as fallows:

```
<Select
  name='layoutValue'
  style={selectStyle}
  options={this.layoutOptions}
  label='Layout'
  value={this.state.layoutValue}
  onChange={this.handleSelectChange}
/>
```

The problem is that on initial render default values (passed in props - from parent's state) aren't selected. SelectField is empty. After i select values manually, everything is ok. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: wants to ask, do your layoutValue variable contains one of the key of layoutOptions ??

Comment: It looks like this, so i think that everything should be fine
`
    this.state = {
      inputUrl: '',
      layoutValue: 0,
      perPageValue: 5,
      error: '',
    };
    this.layoutOptions = { 0: 'Tiles', 1: 'List' };
    this.perPageValueOptions = { 5: '5', 10: '10', 20: '20', 50: '50', 100: '100' };
`

Comment: The second select is build with perPageValueOptions and perPageValue, so that not the 0 problem.

Comment: i think this problem is because of type, try this: layoutValue: '0', instead of giving 0 as int assign it as string, it should work.

Comment: Yep, that was the bug. Thank you!